# How to select and depress a button on click, and undepress all the other buttons?

Tags: jquery, click

I have a set of 3 buttons and I want to code them in a way that when a button is clicked, it is depressed whereas the other 2 buttons go to their default state. I tried the following lines of code in jQuery but the undepress part doesn't seem to work. Would be great to get some help/pointed in the right direction. Classes 'active' and 'default' have been defined in the CSS file.

```
$(function () {
    $('#easybtn').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
            $('#mediumbtn').toggleClass('default');
            $('#hardbtn').toggleClass('default');
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#mediumbtn').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
            $('#easybtn').toggleClass('default');
            $('#hardbtn').toggleClass('default');
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#hardbtn').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
            $('#easybtn').toggleClass('default');
            $('#mediumbtn').toggleClass('default');
    });
});
```

Comment: And the relevant html?

Comment: I didn't think it was necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First assign a common class to all of them... ill call it `difficulty-button` then:

```
$('.difficulty-button').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $all = $('.difficulty-button');

        $all.not($this).toggleClass('active', false).toggleClass('default', true);
        $this.toggleClass('active', true).toggleClass('default', false);
});
```

[Fiddle in action](http://jsfiddle.net/HkcGX/)

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Just needed to add $(function () { before the code and it did what it was supposed to